# Obtain MAC address of remote, unconfigured device?

Tags: arp, mac-address

I have a device that goes on the network.  I need it's MAC address.  There is no label on it.  How do I do that?  I have no access to the device itself.  I can power it on and plug it in to a switch or a laptop, and that's it.  There is no serial port or any other way of interfacing with the device.

To stave off the inevitable, but irrelevant, questions... we need the MAC address to "register" it on the network.  Then it can get an IP address, and then "somebody else" accesses and configures it.  It's a black box to us, but we have to have a MAC to register it.  Yes, this is insane, but we did not design the device or decide to ship it without a label :-)  Please, no responses about how this makes no sense... we know.

Comment: Boot the device up, look at your DHCP server logs for the MAC address.

Comment: What @yoonix said. Or, look at the CAM table of the switch it's connected to.

Comment: Can't - we have no access to the DHCP server.  There is an interface for the switch which might show this.  But I'm looking for some test that I can positively perform... connect a cable to the device and do X to discover the MAC.  If I had a Linux laptop I could install dhcpd, but the only systems I have ready access to are Apple Macs.

Comment: You didn't specify your os. If you run unix you might look to `arp-scan`

Comment: Anything arp related will require it to be configured with an IP address

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the device via a crossover cable or on the same network segment (preferred) via a switch/hub and run a network sniffer (netmon/wireshark/tcpdump) in promiscuous mode to identify the MAC address of the black box.

Answer (score -1):

If you can connect physically to the device, or at least to the same network segment, you might be able to use

```
arp -a
```

to show you the mac address table on your server.

Comment: being connected to same network segment does not guarantee the presence of entry in the host's arp table

Comment: It would require an IP address to have an entry in the arp table